# iPhone low battery notification

Tags: iphone

I was in the process of sending an email and while it was in sending status,
I got the “low battery” iPhone notification pop up

My concern is did it interfere with the email being sent ? I checked and the email was sent successfully so really my question is did that notification send anything to the recipient like does the recepient have any info of my phone did they get any info? Just paranoid

Is there even a connection between the email and the low Battery notification?

Thanks

Comment: Please stop posting the same question

Comment: Yeah I apologize. I just wanted to make it shorter and more clear. You answered on my previous one and I appreciate that. I think you said that the low battery notification and email do not interact? I was just concerned since I wasn’t using the mail client to send the email and while it wasn’t in sending status that’s when the low battery notification popped up.

Comment: My concern really was did that low battery pop up affect the email or recipient in any way or the process of the email? I know this is paranoia and overthinking but did the recipient get anything from my phone and info since that pop up came up when sending them the email